# check if function exist advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having trouble defining a function in advance custom fields.
Basically i need a field populated by a title(text field), a wysiwyg editor and two file upload fields on the bottom of a few product pages.
But i only want to show the field+title if one of the fields is populated.

product info fields are:

product_info_title - Text field

product_info_content - wysiwyg editor

product_info_file_1 - File

product_info_file_2 - File

here is my current acf code in my custom page template:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php 
        if( function_exists('get_field')) {
        if(get_field('product_info_content')) {
        echo '<div class="info-box">';
        echo '<h1>' . get_field('product_info_title') . '</h1>';
        the_field('product_info_content');
        echo '</div>';
        }
        }
        ?>
```

What i can't get to function properly is to check if ANY of the three fields i have besides the title field is populated and if so display it along with the title field.

Comment: Please correct me if i wrong. You are currently want to check if one of three field ( product_info_content, product_info_file_1, product_info_file_2 ) populated and you will show product_info_title field. If what I think was right. Maybe you can use javascript to archive this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show something if one field **OR** another are populated, then you need to use **OR** in your condition:

```
if( field1 OR field2 OR field3 ) {
   // show something
}
```

Applied to your code the condition would be something like:

```
if ( get_field('product_info_content') OR get_field('product_info_file_1')  OR get_field('product_info_file_2') ) {
    // echo the <div>
}
```

Comment: Any of the three fields could be populated, there could be a need for some text or image in the wysiwyg editor, or only a technical data pdf attachment, and when there is no product info at all, the info box field shouldn't show up at all neither.

Comment: trying this code, but the custom page template page crashes when try to echo any of the pdf attachment.